# to change the UITAbleVIewCell shape to round rect

Tags: iphone

how to change shape of rectangular `UITableViewCell (showing customer1 in screenshot[image]) to round rect?

Comment: @stecya: i will take care of that!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not very clear but the screen shot is of group table , if want to make such cells then you can use group table.

Comment: i need to display the cell in round rect in which "customer 2" is displayed! its a cell that i have manually added!! but its soved by adding line of code   tbcel.layer.cornerRadius = 15; in cellForRowAtIndex method thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a cell? Use a Custom Cell :) Look at it [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a group table. You can set the group table style in Interface Builder, or programmatically you need to create the table with that style:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
  // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
  if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]) {
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: i need only to display the cell where "customer 2" is written. It is solved by adding line of code tbcel.layer.cornerRadius = 15; in cellForRowAtIndex method. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-rounded-corners-on-uitableviewcell-image-view/